# Get data from a key value structure and compare it with value from an ng-repeat in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Two  basic questions,

1) I have a controller where I define a list with a key, value structure and I want to access to the event name based on the eventID and log it in the console

```
$scope.events = [
  {eventID:3200, eventName:"Event One"}
  {eventID:3201, eventName:"Event Two"}
];
```

I tried this:

```
  if($scope.events.eventID  == 3200) {
    console.log("Ok");
  }
```

but it didnt worked :(

2) Then in my view I have a table where i print data coming from a WS, what I want is to print the description on the table depending on the eventID from my $scope.events list, I have a field on my ng-repeat named **event** that will let me compare with the eventID from the list but I dont know how to do this.

```
<tr ng repeat d in data>
  <td>d.Description</td>
  <td>d.anyValue</td>
</tr>
```

Any help is welcome, I really need it I'm new to Angular :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for question number 1, try with this

```
if($scope.events[0].eventID  == 3200) {
  console.log("Ok");
}
```

for looping using this

```
angular.forEach($scope.events, function (value) {
  if (value.eventId === 3200) {
  {
    console.log('OK');
  }
});
```

for question number 2, create helper function to return eventName base on the ID.

```
$scope.getEventName = function (eventId) {
  var result = '';
  angular.forEach($scope.events, function (value) {
    if (value.eventID === eventId) {
      result = value.eventName;
      return false;
    }
  });
  return result;
}

<tr ng-repeat="d in (exportDataEventDesc.result.slice(5, exportDataEventDesc.result.length-2))">
  <td>{{d.Description}}</td>
  <td>{{d.anyValue}}</td>
  <td ng-bind="getEventName(d.merchMetrics.EVENT_ID)" style="text-align: left"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time

Comment: Hi mtamma, one more question, to be more specific my ng-repeat is like this:
<tr ng-repeat="d in (exportDataEventDesc.result.slice(5, exportDataEventDesc.result.length-2))"> and next I have this:

<td  ng-bind="d.merchMetrics.EVENT_ID" style="text-align: left"></td> what I need is to put the value of the eventId instead on the default field EVENT_ID.

Comment: What is the difference between var getEventName = function () {} and $scope.getEventName = function () {}

Comment: sorry, it should be $scope.getEventName. so you could access it from view page

Answer (score 3):

Add method in controller

```
$scope.search=function(obj){
  return obj.eventID  === 3200;
}
```

add it to view

```
<tr ng-repeat="d in data | filter:search">
  <td>d.Description</td>
  <td>d.anyValue</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time =)